# Visual Studio 2022 Intellisense Hides Incompatible Members in Suggestions, but why?

Tags: c++, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

I believe one of the more recent updates to Visual Studio has added some new ability to Intellisense that leads it to hide type members from suggestions when they are not compatible with the current function parameter. For example, if the function parameter expects an `int`, it will hide everything that is not an `int`.

However, there is a huge (and pretty obvious) problem with this strategy. What if I need to find a member that contains another member that **will be** compatible? For some reason, Microsoft seems to have not considered this, unless I've done something to cause this behavior myself in the settings.

Is anyone aware of a setting to disable this new feature?

Comment: This is why I prefer to use the version of Intellisense that's between my ears. It'll never suggest the wrong thing. It's always right. I never need to disable it. In fact, if something disables it, I'll be in big trouble.

Comment: I find Intellisense is next to useless on large projects. It gets in the way so much, and gets so utterly tangled in itself, I wish it wasn't there at all.

Comment: My project is currently around 2K source files, and unfortunately, the memory bandwidth between my ears would have me popping back and forth between files every few lines of code without Intellisense. It usually behaves pretty well for me, and when it doesn't, I just delete the .vs folder to fix it. But this new feature is pretty annoying. It's hard to imagine why anyone thought this feature was ready to be activated.

Comment: I think I may have found the option @ **Options > C/C++ > Experimental > Enable Predictive Intellisense**. I've disabled this option before and still got strange results, so assumed it wasn't it, but now it seems to fix it when I turn it off. Will test for a while to make sure.